# Re-entering USA after short trip to Canada after visa expired

Tags: visas, transit-visas, b1-b2-visas, standard-visitor-visas, j1-visas

My J-1 visa will expire on the 14th of December 2018 and I am aware of the 30 day grace period however, I was planning to go to Canada for 4 days to visit my family friends for Christmas (during the 30 day grace period) and want to know if I will be allowed back into the US to catch my already booked flight home from LA?

I dont want to risk going there if I am going to miss my flight home from LA but really wanted to see my friends as it has been many years and I rarely get to come to the US.

I know there is no guarentee of re-entry but was wondering if anyone has any experience, or knowledge of this?

Thanks!

Comment: A US State Dept page on J-1 visas here: https://j1visa.state.gov/participants/current/adjustments-and-extensions/ contains the following language: "Although participants may travel in the United States, it is recommended that they do not travel beyond the borders of the United States as they may not be permitted reentry." This does not seem encouraging of your planned travel, which apparently has a significant risk of stranding you outside the US. Not posted as an Answer, as I have no personal experience or knowledge of this issue.

Comment: What is your nationality? And has your program ended?

Comment: I am Australian. I have heard i might be able to get an ESTA?

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/62657/will-i-be-able-to-travel-out-of-us-without-a-valid-visa/62658#62658 however I can't mark it as such due to the bounty, which seems like a bug to me...